# How do I install GNOME Tweak Tool in Kubuntu 17.10?

Tags: gnome, kubuntu, tweak

When I try to install `gnome-tweak-tool` with APT, it tells me `gnome-tweak-tool` is already the newest version, so what am I doing wrong?

[image: terminal window]

Comment: which means that gnome-tweak-tool is already installed.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's already installed, however gnome tweak tool won't help you much, if you are using plasma you should tweak your stuff from system settings.

Answer (score 2):

GNOME Tweak Tool, as the name suggests, is used to tweak the appearance of the GNOME desktop which is now the default on Ubuntu 17.10. However, since Kubuntu has always had the KDE Plasma desktop, it won't tweak anything much here.

Instead Plasma itself comes with almost all the tweaks the GNOME Tweak Tool could offer and much much more. Just go to the appearance settings of the desktop and tweak all you want.

If you still need to test what GNOME tweaks can do, you need to `sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop` first. Then you can log in to GNOME and use the tweak tool.